# Where EntityResource constructor is called?

Tags: java, rest, model-view-controller, jhipster

I have jHipster Project with 2 Entities - User and Client. Client has field "user_id" which keeps user_id of that user which created a client entity.

ClientResource.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ClientResource {

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "client";
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientResource.class);
    private final ClientService clientService;

    private final UserService userService;

    private final ClientQueryService clientQueryService;

    public ClientResource(ClientService clientService, ClientQueryService clientQueryService, UserService userService) {
        this.clientService = clientService;
        this.clientQueryService = clientQueryService;
        this.userService = userService;
     }
```

....................

```
@PostMapping("/clients")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<ClientDTO> createClient(@RequestBody ClientDTO clientDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to save Client : {}", clientDTO);
    if (clientDTO.getId() != null) {
        throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new client cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
    }

    String login = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().toString();
    Long loggedUserId = userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(login).get().getId();
```

Here i got exception:
Exception in com.mycompany.hiptest.web.rest.ClientResource.createClient() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'No value present'

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

I guess because i haven' a initilized clientService variable.
But how clientService got value? I didn't found any calls of ClientResource constructor.

Comment: Could you please tell us which line from your code caused the exception? You can see it in the exception stacktrace. Thank you!

Comment: This line :
       Long loggedUserId = userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(login).get().getId();

Comment: This is only a guess, but probably the call to userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(login) is typed to Optional and returns an Optional.empty() and the following get() then causes the exception.

Comment: That means, the caller is not logged-in.

Comment: Yes , you right,  but I  logged in as admin and ordinary user - same result. I couldn't  get menu item for adding a client without being logged in.

Comment: The constructor is injected by Spring as you can easily check it under debugger otherwise your app would not start.